# How does Bigquery ML encode string features for prediction?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm evaluating the performance of a binary logistic regression model built on BigQuery ML.

I'm using four string fields. Each one of them is a sentence. The only preprocessing applied has been turning them into lowercase. None of these strings is a list or embedding vector.

This binary classifier is performing quite well on the validation set and I want to know why.

I want to know how the model is encoding/representing these textual features and I have not found it on the BigQuery ML documentation.

Does Bigquery ML encode string fields as bags of words or word2vec/doc2vec vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a model to give you the exact way to see the model details.

This is a simple linear regression model:

```
CREATE MODEL `deleting.stringtest`
OPTIONS ( model_type='linear_reg')
AS 
SELECT 'hello' text, 1 label
UNION ALL
SELECT 'goodbye' text, 2 label
UNION ALL
SELECT 'hello goodbye my friend' text, 2 label
```

Once this model is created, you can take a peek at the model weights:

```
SELECT *
FROM ML.WEIGHTS(MODEL `deleting.stringtest`)
```

[image]

What you can see here is a simple one-hot encoding where each different whole string in the input is given it's own dimension. No splitting has been done.